# How can I diagnose in Wilfly why security domain in Elytron, based on LDAP realm fails

Tags: logging, wildfly

I am trying to set up web application authentication against Active Directory using Elytron in Wildfly 16.

Deployment fails. This question is not that much about Elytron configuration, but as background info, here are the symptoms I am trying to get a hang of:

- If the Undertow application-security-domain points at the http-authentication-factory in Elytron, deployment results in "*There is no mechanisms available from the HttpAuthenticationFactory*".
- If the application-security-domain points directly at the elytron security-domain, the error message is "*The required mechanism 'BASIC' is not available in mechanisms [CLIENT_CERT, FORM] from the HttpAuthenticationFactory*"

I cannot figure out what went wrong from this. I tried configuring the logging subsystem setting TRACE logging level on different categories but no effect.

**Question:**
How can I enable more detailed logging on what's happening inside Elytron in order to see if the problem is in the ldap-realm configuration or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Basically, the main problem was that my logging configuration for org.wildfly.security wrote only to the standalone instance log file. I was watching only the NetBeans Wildfly Application Server Output window, where these trace items did not show.